# MYSQL Select two tables with multiple which is not there

Tags: mysql

I try to use LEFT JOIN but I dont get the result I want.
I have 2 tables

Table 1:

```
Persons

UID  | Names   | GID   
1    | Mike    | 1
2    | Tom     | 1    
3    | Brenda  | 1    
4    | Sophie  | 2
```

Table 2:

```
DailyLog

ID | UID   | GID | DATE    
1  | 1     | 1   | 2017-10-13    
2  | 2     | 1   | 2017-10-13    
3  | 3     | 1   | 2017-10-13    
4  | 1     | 1   | 2017-10-13    
5  | 2     | 1   | 2017-10-14    
6  | 1     | 1   | 2017-10-14
7  | 1     | 1   | 2017-10-15
```

I want search a name who is not have a stamp date of today (2017-10-15) in GID 1,
    a result like this:

```
UID | Name     
2   | Tom    
3   | Brenda
```

I use SQL Left Join, but the result not what I expected.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.uid
              , a.Name
              , b.date 
           FROM Persons AS a 
           LEFT 
           JOIN dailylog AS b 
             ON a.uid = b.uid 
            AND a.gid = b.gid 
          WHERE (b.date IS NULL OR b.date !='2017-10-15' ) 
            AND a.gid='1'

Thank you
```

Comment: GL, who believes in giving the world a fish, will answer this in a couple of seconds, but you might like to see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Here is a starting point - please copy from this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6db4c7/7

Comment: And why not Mike?

Comment: Thank you so much, it work like what I want the result is.

Comment: @Indra You're not making a whole lot of sense.

Comment: @strawbery 
I tried with http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5210f2/2
and the result come out as I expected.
and for the mike i made a typo.

Comment: There's an edit button; useful for correcting errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a not In clause

```
SELECT  a.uid
      , a.Name
      , b.date 
FROM Persons
where uid not in (
  select uid from DailyLog
  where GID = 1 
  and  DATE = '2017-10-15'
)
```

Comment: `DISTINCT`? You expect to find duplicates in the persons table?

Comment: Thanks, now I got the result as I expected.
instead of using LEFT JOIN, its a better using NOT IN